# How to query sharepoint online data when folder is having more than 5000 documents

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint online site In which one folder is having more than 5000 records. The rest api is giving an error. **The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold**.
If is use call - /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/Items. this is working fine but I want the documents from one particular folder so for that I am using call - _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath() which is giving error of threshold.

Is there any way to get folders data using title call of sharepoint online.

Note - title field is indexed in share point online.

Comment: Related (without answer yet, though): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292288/sharepoint-rest-api-retrieve-more-than-5000-files-in-folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetFolderByServerRelativePath(). To avoid the limitation you can call 5000 items each time, until you get all data (recursively), using the d.__next property:

```
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/folderName/innerFolder')/Files?$top=5000";
    var response = [];  // this variable is used for storing list items
 GetListItems();

function GetListItems(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,  
        method: "GET",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
        },
        success: function(data){
            response = response.concat(data.d.results);
            console.log(response);
            if (data.d.__next) {
                url = data.d.__next;
                GetListItems();
            }
            
        },
        error: function(error){
           console.log(error);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I have used GetFolderByServerRelativePath() with top value 20 still It is giving the same error. <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.</m:message>
</m:error>